# Putting nodes identified by element into one node

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to use some xslt and i have no idea where to start, hope you guys could at least give me some clues.

Source xml

```
<ROW>
    <DEPT> A </DEPT>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DEPT> B </DEPT>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DEPT> A </DEPT>
</ROW>
```

Target xml

```
<DEPTARTMENT>
    <ROW>
        <DEPT> A </DEPT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <DEPT> A </DEPT>
    </ROW>
</DEPARTMENT>
<DEPTARTMENT>
    <ROW>
        <DEPT> B </DEPT>
    </ROW>
</DEPARTMENT>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible XSLT 1.0 solution.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kRowByDept" match="ROW" use="DEPT"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <T>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="ROW[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRowByDept', DEPT)[1])]"/>
    </T>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <DEPARTMENT>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowByDept', DEPT)"/>
    </DEPARTMENT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML (wrapped in a top-level element to make the document well-formed):**

```
<T>
  <ROW>
    <DEPT> A </DEPT>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <DEPT> B </DEPT>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <DEPT> A </DEPT>
  </ROW>
</T>
```

**...the desired solution is produced:**

```
<T>
  <DEPARTMENT>
    <ROW>
      <DEPT> A </DEPT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <DEPT> A </DEPT>
    </ROW>
  </DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT>
    <ROW>
      <DEPT> B </DEPT>
    </ROW>
  </DEPARTMENT>
</T>
```

**Explanation:**

This is a solution that uses [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), an XSLT 1.0-specific method for grouping elements together.

---

Here is an analogous XSLT 2.0 solution; note that it is *much* more straightforward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <T>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ROW" group-by="DEPT">
        <DEPARTMENT>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
        </DEPARTMENT>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </T>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can not think about more complete answer, thank you very much!